# Change the color of a ToolStripProgressBar without disabling the XP Visual Styles?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, progress-bar

In a Winforms I would like to change the back color of a `ToolStripProgressBar` without disablng the `XP Visual Syles` for the entire application, is this possibly? maybe disabling XP Visual Styles only for the `StatusStrip` control?

I know that a ToolStripProgressBar doesn't inherits from a Control type, but an StatusStrip does (not?), then sure that must be a solution, or maybe inheriting the StatusStrip for controlling the paint events or something else... I don't know how to do it.

I've tried to set the `RenderMode` property of my `StatusStrip` control to profesional mode but the system is still choosing the backcolor for myToolStripProgressBar.

Comment: since `VisualStyles` is enabled at the Application level (`Application.EnableVisualStyles`) you might be out of luck.  `Forms` has a `VisualStyles` Namespace and the progressbar inherits from that, but that Namespace is more for applying those VisualStyles it seems.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this can't be done without you doing all the painting yourselves.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can customize the look and feel of the `ProgressBar` hosted by the `ToolStripControlHost` named `ToolStripProgressBar`. You can access to the hosted `ProgressBar` via the property `ProgressBar` of a `ToolStripProgressBar`. You then can add the `Paint` event handler for that `ProgressBar`. However this `Paint` event is fired only if the control style `UserPaint` is set for the `ProgressBar`, that's by designed (and of course different from other normal controls which support the `Paint` event by default). So you can try the following code. In fact I tried commenting out the line `Application.EnableVisualStyles();` to see what actually you want with a non-XP-Style `ToolStripProgressBar` and looks like it's too simple, the following code should do what you want:

```
//define some variables first, note that don't rely on the 
//ProgressBarRenderer.ChunkThickness and ProgressBarRenderer.ChunkSpaceThickness
//because they are actually small and using our own variables will allow us to change
//the chunk size easily.
int chunkThickness = 13;
int chunkSpace = 1;
Rectangle chunkRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, chunkThickness,
                          toolStripProgressBar1.ProgressBar.Height-4);
//The hosted ProgressBar's Paint event handler
private void progressBar_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e){
  chunkRect.Location = Point.Empty;
  chunkRect.Offset(2, 2);                
  var percent = (float) toolStripProgressBar1.Value / toolStripProgressBar1.Maximum;
  var valueLength = percent * toolStripProgressBar1.ProgressBar.Width;
  var chunks = (int) (valueLength / (chunkThickness + chunkSpace) + 0.5f);
  for (int i = 0; i < chunks; i++) {
     //I use the green color for the chunk color, it's up to you.
     e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Green, chunkRect);                    
     chunkRect.Offset(chunkThickness + chunkSpace, 0);
  }
  ControlPaint.DrawBorder3D(e.Graphics, toolStripProgressBar1.ProgressBar.ClientRectangle,
                           Border3DStyle.SunkenOuter);
}
//Now in your form constructor, just add this code to end up everything before
//trying running the code:
public Form1(){
   InitializeComponent();
   //do this to allow the Paint event to be fired and more ...
   typeof(Control).GetMethod("SetStyle", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                         System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance)
                  .Invoke(toolStripProgressBar1.ProgressBar, 
                          new object[] {ControlStyles.UserPaint |
                                        ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true });
   //hook up the progressBar_Paint event handler for the hosted ProgressBar
   toolStripProgressBar1.ProgressBar.Paint += progressBar_Paint;
}
```

Isn't this look and feel what you're waiting for?:

[image]

**Update**: for continuous progress bar, it's much simpler than the blocks style, try the following updated `progressBar_Paint`:

```
private void progressBar_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e){
  var percent = (float) toolStripProgressBar1.Value / toolStripProgressBar1.Maximum;
  var valueLength = percent * toolStripProgressBar1.ProgressBar.Width;
  var chunkRect = new RectangleF(2,2,valueLength,
                                 toolStripProgressBar1.ProgressBar.Height-4);
  e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Green, chunkRect);
  ControlPaint.DrawBorder3D(e.Graphics, toolStripProgressBar1.ProgressBar.ClientRectangle,
                           Border3DStyle.SunkenOuter);
}
```

Comment: @ElektroStudios it's much simpler than implementing a block-styled progressbar, see my update for the code.

Comment: Before seeying your update I've resolved it adjusting the chunkspace value that's why I've deleted my comment, sorry for give you more work, it's my fault for didn't noticed those variables, thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

I just want to share my vbnet approach based on @King King C# Answer.

I've tried to modify it for generic use but the code stills be a little hardcoded.

```
''' <summary>
''' The Backcolor to fill the ToolStrip ProgressBar.
''' </summary>
Private ProgressBar_BackColor As Brush = New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(120, 147, 73))

''' <summary>
''' The ForeColor to fill the ToolStrip ProgressBar.
''' </summary>
Private ProgressBar_ForeColor As Brush = New SolidBrush(Color.Black)

''' <summary>
''' Draws a border effect inside the bounds of the ProgressBar.
''' </summary>
Private ProgressBar_Border As Single = 0

''' <summary>
''' Indicates the StringFormat of the ProgressBar Text.
''' </summary>
Private ProgressBar_Text_Format As StringFormat =
    New StringFormat With {.Alignment = Drawing.StringAlignment.Center,
                           .Trimming = StringTrimming.EllipsisCharacter}


Public Sub New()

    ' Necessary call to the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Set the Style of the ToolStripProgesssBar (For be able to fill the progressbar with a custom color).
    GetType(Control).GetMethod("SetStyle", Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic Or Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance).
                     Invoke(ToolStripProgressBar1.ProgressBar,
                            New Object() {ControlStyles.UserPaint Or ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, True})

End Sub

' ProgressBarStatus [Paint]
Private Sub ProgressBarStatus_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) _
Handles ToolStripProgressBar1.Paint

    ' Fill the progressbar
    Select Case sender.style

        Case ProgressBarStyle.Continuous

            ' The ProgressBar Rectangle.
            Dim ProgressBarRect As RectangleF =
                New RectangleF(ProgressBar_Border / 2, ProgressBar_Border / 2,
                               CSng(sender.Value / sender.Maximum) * CSng(sender.ProgressBar.Width - ProgressBar_Border),
                               sender.ProgressBar.Height - ProgressBar_Border)

            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(ProgressBar_BackColor, ProgressBarRect)

        Case ProgressBarStyle.Blocks

            ' The Width of each block.
            Dim BlockWidth As Integer = 10

            ' The space between each block.
            Dim BlockSpace As Integer = 1

            ' The ProgressBar Rectangle.
            Dim ProgressBarRect As Rectangle =
                New Rectangle(0, 0, BlockWidth, sender.ProgressBar.Height - 4)

            ' Calculate the block count.
            Dim PercentDone As Single = CSng(sender.ProgressBar.Value / sender.ProgressBar.Maximum)
            Dim valueLength As Single = PercentDone * CSng(sender.ProgressBar.Width)
            Dim BlockCount As Integer = CInt(valueLength / (BlockWidth + BlockSpace) + 0.5F)

            ProgressBarRect.Offset(2, 2)

            For i As Integer = 0 To BlockCount - 1
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(ProgressBar_BackColor, ProgressBarRect)
                ProgressBarRect.Offset(BlockWidth + BlockSpace, 0)
            Next

            ControlPaint.DrawBorder3D(e.Graphics, sender.ProgressBar.ClientRectangle, Border3DStyle.SunkenOuter)

    End Select

    ' Draw the Text
    Dim TextBounds As Rectangle = sender.ProgressBar.Bounds
    TextBounds.Inflate(0, 4) ' Correct the Text position.

    Using fnt As New Font(CType(sender.ProgressBar.Font.FontFamily, FontFamily),
                          CSng(sender.ProgressBar.Font.SizeInPoints) + 1,
                          FontStyle.Bold)

        e.Graphics.DrawString(sender.ProgressBar.Value, fnt, ProgressBar_ForeColor, TextBounds, ProgressBar_Text_Format)

    End Using

End Sub
```